# Passagem de parâmetro entre camadas

Tags: c#

Estou iniciando na linguagem c# e estou com um problema na passagem de parâmetros entre camadas. No meu programa eu fiz 3 camadas, a Dal, Modelo e a de interface. Quando eu tento comparar um valor de retorno da camada Dal na camada de interface, eu não consigo, mas se eu copio o código da camada dal e jogo na interface, ele funciona normalmente. Segue os códigos:

Ps. Esse código é um teste para um projeto a parte, mas estou testando por partes.

Camada interface:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dal da = new Dal();
        Modelo mo = new Modelo();
        int s = 1;
        int r = 1;
        mo.idade = textBox1.Text;
        mo.sexo = textBox2.Text;

        if (da.Verificar(r) == 1 && da.Verificar2(s) == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ja possui um registro no sistema!");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não possui nenhum registro no sistema");

        }


    }
```

Camada Modelo:

```
    private string nIdade;
    private string nSexo;

    public string idade
    {
        get { return nIdade; }
        set { nIdade = value; }
    }

    public string sexo
    {
        get { return nSexo; }
        set { nSexo = value; }
    }
```

Camada Dal:

```
    private static string caminho = "server=localhost;port=3306;database=cadastro;User Id=root;password=";
    private MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection(caminho);
    private Modelo mo = new Modelo();


    public int Verificar(int r)
    {    
        //Comando de verificação de registro.
        string verifica = "select * from pessoas where idade = '"+ mo.idade+"'";
        MySqlCommand verificar = new MySqlCommand(verifica, conexao);

        conexao.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dr = verificar.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            r = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            r = 0;
        }
        conexao.Close();
        return r;
    }

    public int Verificar2(int s)
    {          
        //Comando de verificação de registro.    
        string verifica2 = "select * from pessoas where sexo = '" + mo.sexo + "'";
        MySqlCommand verificar2 = new MySqlCommand(verifica2, conexao);

        conexao.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dr2 = verificar2.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr2.HasRows)
        {
            s = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            s = 0;
        }
        conexao.Close();
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: O que quer dizer com "não consigo"? Não será por falta de algum `using`?

Comment: A pergunta é boa, mas comente no código onde está dando erro e nos mostre quais as mensagens de erro. Ao perguntar leve em conta a nossa perspectiva do código, o que para você é uma parte concatenada a um todo para nós é apenas um fragmento carecendo de mais informações.

Comment: o seu 'dal' não funciona corretamente pois você está passando o sexo e a idade no modelo que está na 'interface', na 'dal' você está apenas instanciando modelo sem passar nenhum parametro

Answer (score 2):

Saudações.

A sua resposta foi respondida nos comentários pelo @Lucas Miranda. Veja:

```
public int Verificar(Modelo mo)// aqui você deve receber o objeto Modelo
    {    
        int r;// aqui a variável que você usa como verificação. obs: eu usaria um bool e mudaria o tipo de retorno.
        //Comando de verificação de registro.
        string verifica = "select * from pessoas where idade = '"+ mo.idade+"'";
        MySqlCommand verificar = new MySqlCommand(verifica, conexao);

        conexao.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dr = verificar.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
            r = 1;// apenas uma linha não precisa de chaves, fica a seu critériio
        else
            r = 0;
        conexao.Close();
        return r;
    }
```

O mesmo deve ser feito no método `Verificar2`

A chamada no botão ficaria assim:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dal da = new Dal();
        Modelo mo = new Modelo();

        mo.idade = textBox1.Text;
        mo.sexo = textBox2.Text;

        if (da.Verificar(mo) == 1 && da.Verificar2(mo) == 1)
            MessageBox.Show("Ja possui um registro no sistema!");// uma linha só no if não precisa das chaves, mas isso fica a seu critério
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Não possui nenhum registro no sistema");
    }
```

Eu não cheguei a testar o código aqui, veja se entendeu o conceito e caso tenha dúvidas ainda estamos aqui para ajudar.Abraço.

Comment: Obrigado cara, eu fiquei de verificar a pergunta que eu tinha feito, me desculpa mas tinha dado certo.

Comment: Fico feliz que deu certo. Abraço...